# Finding element in jquery

Tags: jquery, list, css-selectors

How to find the first and last li dynamically using jquery?

The finding of li should accept in all lists in document..

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
 {
$('li:first-child').addClass('first');
 $('li:last-child').addClass('last');});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('li:first')
$('li:last');
```

This is a way to find first and last in a list.

Answer (score 1):

`$('li:first')` and `:last`, respectively.

In response to your edit, `li:first-child` will yield all `li` elements that are the first child of their respective parent nodes. Whereas `li:first` will yield only the very first `li` element in the document.

Comment: In addition, there are the `.first()` and `.last()` methods as well.

Comment: In addition n°2 , place this in the $(document).ready(function({ //CODE GOES HERE  })); (the data must be loaded first before trying to get its value)

Answer (score 0):

Add class to `li` say `someclass` if you have number of the `li` on page

```
$('.someclass').last();
$('.someclass').first();
```

Or just

```
$('li:first')
$('li:last');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the first and last `li` of all list elements on the page you can do:

`$('li:first')` and `$('li:last')`

If you need to find the first and last list elements within each list:

```
$('ul, ol').each(function() {
  $('li:first', this); 
  $('li:last', this);
});
```

Comment: Your each condition could in most scenarios be reduced to `li:first-child` and `:last-child`. The only exceptions being where there are elements in the lists that are not `li` elements (as is the case in nested lists, for example)